# One table entry per given period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering whether you can create a constraint in SQL ensuring that a user doesn't enter more than one entry per given period of time.

For example: if it was once a day, I would imagine you could create a composite key such as: (UserID, Day, Month, Year).

Is there a more proper way of doing it? Could you do it for any time interval?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this assuming the time intervals are defined on the calendar time line.  That is, it is easy to set up for once per week.  It is a bit harder (i.e. requires triggers) to set up for "at least one week between entries".

To do this, you can use a computed column and unique index.  For instance, the following ensures just one entry per calendar year:

```
alter table t add theyear as year(datecol);

create unique index t_user_theyear on t(user, theyear);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

> you shouldn't

is unsatisfying, so I'll try to explain better.

The functionality you describe is not directly bound to persistence. The database has the responsibility to persist data while any domain-specific logic does not pertain to that tier.

You should place that logic into a domain-specific tier, naturally in the web server's code.

SQL is not limited or whatever, but it cannot take into account all domain-specific cases and nuances, while a web-server is there exactly for that :)

Say your intervals are next to arbitrary (not aligned to hours, days or whatever data may be available to the database). You'll have to make discrete the time value. But that function may be arbitrarily complex, like this:

```
dicrete_time(t) ::= floor((t / 5 + 3) * (t * 2))
```

As long as it is [monotonic increasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) there is no way to tell how *time* is mapped to *discrete time*. So this should not be implemented on a database server. It is out of scope.

Comment: I do partially agree with you. However the moment the system is used for medical purposes and the data comes from different sources (rather than one Web Service) having constraints that might save somebody's life would definitely be nice.

Comment: For real systems on which lives depend all nations require adherence to specific standards (e.G. [mil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-498)). From those you'll have constraints that don't let you do stuff like this "because it's technically feasible" but require appropriate design documents. So the problem shifts from implementation to design and the answer will, still, probably be "you shouldn't".

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on schema level, because column constraints work separately for each row, isolated from the rest of the table.

You can create a table trigger where you can implement all these checks, however complex they may be. If you cannot control all sources of data, that's probably the only viable option.